# mySQL count and get maximum from table

Tags: mysql, count, max

I have a simple question. I have this table structure http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61cee/3/0 and I just want to count score of each player which are attacker and then pick the highest score from all players and his id. I tried this:

```
SELECT MAX(counts), id_player FROM 
  (SELECT COUNT(score) AS counts, id_player
   FROM fl_poll 
   WHERE position = 'attacker' 
   GROUP BY id_player) as maxi
```

But the result is wrong id. Where I made a mistake? Thanks for advance.

Comment: Do you a tie on max(counts)?

Comment: The problem is that you are selecting `id_player` in the outer query: "[*The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-extensions.html)".  @davek's answer is the best solution in this case, although the more general answer to this "[groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)" problem is to join the subquery back to the data underlying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   SELECT COUNT(score) AS counts, id_player
   FROM fl_poll 
   WHERE position = 'attacker' 
   GROUP BY id_player
   ORDER BY COUNT(score) desc
   LIMIT 1
```